# Exploring Expectation Identity

Tags: probability, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

Let $X\sim N(\mu ,\sigma^2)$ and g : $\Bbb R$ $\to$ $\Bbb R$ be a differentiable function and $E[|g'(X)|] < \infty$.

a) Show that $E[g'(X)] = \sigma^{-2}E[g(X)(X-\mu)]$

b) Make use of the above identity to derive the n-th moment of $X$, for $n\ge3$ (recursive form is enough).

My attempt:

a) $$g'(X)=\frac{-(X-\mu)}{\sigma^2}g(X)$$

and

$$E[g(X)(X-\mu)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(x-\mu)}g(x)f_X(x)dx$$
$$=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\sigma^2(\frac{-(x-\mu)}{\sigma^2}g(x))f_X(x)dx$$

then I put the $g'(X)$ in and get $E[g(X)(X-\mu)]=-\sigma^2E[g'(X)]$ which is wrong because I got a negative sign.

b) $n^{th}$ moment of $X$ is $E[X^n] = M_X^{(n)}(0)$ and $M_X=E[e^{tX}]$, but I can't think of a way to define the MGF.

Comment: What does you first step in a) mean? LHS is a random variable and RHS is not.

Comment: The formula in a) is wrong when $g(x)=x$ and $\mu =0$. Are you sure you have copied the question correctly?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry! I made some mistakes. I have corrected it now. Thank you :)

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly relevant for legibility if you mix fractions and exponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use integration by part :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[g'(X)] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g'(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left( -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)\\
&= -\left[ g(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left( -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \right]_{-\infty}^\infty + \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left( -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)\\
&= 0+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbb E[g(X) (X-\mu)]
\end{align*}
The first term goes to zero, otherwise $g'$ is not absolutely integrable.

For the n'th moment you can use the function $g(x)=(x-\mu)^{n-1}$ with derivative $(n-1) (x-\mu)^{n-2}$ to obtain $\mathbb E[(x-\mu)^n]=\sigma^2(n-1) \mathbb E[(x-\mu)^{n-2}]$

Comment: isn't $g'(x) = (n-1)(x-\mu)^{n-2}$? and $\Bbb{E}[(x-\mu)^n]$ is the central moment right? How do I find the raw moment?

Comment: Yes sorry, for the normal moment you can use $g(x)=x^{n-1}$ and separate all the term to get a recurrence relation.

Comment: My final answer is $\Bbb{E}[X^{n-2}]=\frac{1}{(n-1)\sigma^2}\Bbb{E}[X^{n-1}(X-\mu)]$ is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is also $\Bbb{E}[X^{n-2}]=\frac{1}{(n-1)\sigma^2}\Bbb{E}[X^n] - \frac{\mu}{(n-1)\sigma^2}\Bbb{E}[X^{n-1}]$.